# ASP.Net MVC Page Load

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC application for a website.

Currently I have a hyperlink `<a href="navigation/MainNavLevel2/2"><h2>Navigation</h2></a>`

I would like the contents of this to be displayed once the page loads instead of having to click on the hyperlink.

Can anyone assist in show my how to do this?

Comment: You may have gotten away with using an `iframe` and not needing jQuery at all.

Comment: How do I do this without jquery? The problem I have is the code I have put below does work but having a problem with formatting the values from a `div` into a `h3` reference

Comment: just tried iframe but doesnt seem to work on mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the content of my div when the page loads, I used the code below to call the libraries:

`<h2="libraries"></h2>`

Created some javascript:

```
<script src="../..Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#libraries').load('navigation/MainNavLevel2/2');

</script>
```

This then loads the content of navigation/MainNav/Level2/2 into my h2.